# Run 4 mysql queries at once in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, data-integrity

I wrote a Java application to add articles to a Joomla site.
I'm using JDBC to connect and run queries on Mysql database.
To create an article I need to run a query on `_contents` table (an insert) and 3 queries on `_assets` table (Two Updates & One Insert).
the three queries that should be executed on `_assets` table are used to insert an item to a "Nested List Tree"; so if one of these queries fail the Nested List Tree will break.
My program is accessing to database from a remote system (So Internet connectivity problems or anything else can interrupt queries).
How can I get sure that all three queries run with each other without any of them get missed?

Thanks

Comment: You can start a new database transaction before doing those queries and commit the transaction after all are executed. That way if one of them fails, the previous queries will be cancelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think transactions is what you are looking for.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Unfortunatly MySQL MYISAM engine doesn't support Transactions!

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention MyISAM in your question. If you can't change the relevant tables to InnoDB probably the best you can do is check after each query and continue only if successful. StoredProcs serverside do not help as they do not guarantee transactional behaviour (atomicity)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Mysql-Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) in a "stored procedure" that combines your 4 queries.
This way I think it is more likely that your update succeeds (on the database, your Java-method may fail I think). and if you are planing to use other programs/ programing languages the handling of your update will be the same and you won't have to care any further.

However, if you are just using one Java program, I would use transactions on the Java-side, because for me Java is easier than sql (especially if you use spring and a persistence provider like for example hibernate ([Spring Transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/transaction.html), [hibernate transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html))).

Comment: Unfortunatly MySQL MYISAM engine doesn't support Transactions!